# How to organize the distributed integration testing

Tags: testing, parallel-processing, distributed-computing

I have an application for desktop OS Windows. There is an ability to pass command line arguments to app. In arguments I can pass a path to file with test scenario and run test. When test complete, app generates report files and compares them with reference files. I have several thousands tests. I want to use computers in local network and run test there. I need an ability to transfer over local network an application, test scenarios, reference files, run app and get back report files. Is there a simple solution to my task ?